# Delete the installer after installation

Tags: electron, electron-builder

I'm trying to have the installer [NSIS] deleted after my electron app is installed on a device, so that the user needn't do so

Is there a possible way to achieve this

Answer (score 2):

So I would not really recommend it but you could try to use the `Delete` function, specify your installer-file and set the `/REBOOTOK` Flag.

The code would look something like this:

`Delete  path\myInstaller.exe /REBOOTOK`

This Flag tries to Delete the File right away and if it fails, wich it will since the installer is running, it will delete it after a reboot.

Just keep in mind that you would have to reboot your computer after the installation or the file will not be deleted.

Let me know if this solved your problem.